# subprocess to call exe file not working in pyinstaller exe file

Tags: python, subprocess, pyinstaller, exe

I have a 3rd party exe file which has dependencies on multiple 3rd party dll files.
The exe and dlls are not in the same folder.

So, I wrote a simple python script and works properly in my IDE:

```
import subprocess
import os

def my_func():
    exe_path = 'EXE_PATH'
    dll_folder_path = 'DLL_FOLDER_PATH'

    subprocess.Popen(exe_path, shell=True, cwd=dll_folder_path)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_func()
```

The code works fine in IDE but I am getting an issue when running the pyinstaller exe file.

The 3rd party exe file gets called but it seems the `dll_folder_path` is not getting recognized for some reason.
I am getting an error: The code execution cannot proceed because XXX.dll was not found.
I've also tried adding other `subprocess` arguments like `stdout`, `stderr` but seems not helping.

my pyinstaller command was: `pyinstaller --onefile --clean my_func.py`

adding dll_folder to windows path is not an option for me and I have hundreds of 3rd party exe file like this so trying to build some helper.

OS: windows 10

---

Comment: Are `dll_folder_path` and `exe_path` absolute or relative paths?

Comment: They are both absolute paths.

Comment: PyInstaller calls SetDllDirectory so that some ctypes modules will work as expected. This behavior is Windows specific. You need to check if you can work without this and then use `SetDllDirectory(None)` at the start of your python script. This is because child process inherit the dll directory from the parent process if it's set. This is apparently undocumented (in Windows itself, pyinstaller documents this in their wiki)